# Fastest method to filter and get a chunk of a list of strings

Tags: python, list

I have a huge list of tag strings that should be filtered by a given tag_filter.
The returned joined string should contain 20 max tags `\n` separated.
The code, right now, looks like this:

```
tags = Tag.get_tags() #This returns the list of tags strings
return '\n'.join([tag for tag in tags if tag.startswith(tag_filter)][:20])
```

How can I improve it avoiding to scan all the tags list after 20 tags are matched?
I'm using **Python 2.5**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a genex and [`itertools.islice()`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice).

```
'\n'.join(itertools.islice((tag for tag in tags if tag.startswith(tag_filter)), 20))
```

Answer (score 1):

See the [itertools recipies](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def take(n, iterable):
    "Return first n items of the iterable as a list"
    return list(islice(iterable, n))
```

so in your case

```
return '\n'.join(take(20, (tag for tag in tags if tag.startswith(tag_filter))))
```

**Edit:** Really, the `list` call is unnecessary in this case because of `join` so just using `islice` as in Ignacio's answer is adequate.